# Error illegal start of expression while using lambdas in java 8

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, syntax-error

I have recently updated my java to the 8th version and trying some Lambdas but it's giving error.

My Code

```
String[] st = {"ak","ss","dd"};

Arrays.asList(st).forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));
```

The output of the console is

```
PS E:\> javac .\Lambdas.java
.\Lambdas.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
                   Arrays.asList(st).forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));
                                                   ^
1 error
PS E:\> java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

This is strange because I have java 8 as seen above but my code in not compiling.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: As far as im aware `->` isn't valid syntax in java.

Comment: @Aʟᴀɢᴀʀᴏs: it is in Java8, when using Lambda expressions. Unless there is a space between - and >

Comment: just a shot in the dark... but could you try javac -version

Comment: Can you please check that javac is the same version too? `javac -version`

Comment: Works fine for me ! Please post output of `javac -version` .

Comment: @codegasmer : the good news is, your code is correct and works as it is intended. bad new, of course, means that it 'll be a bit harder to debug

Comment: @fdreger, BackSlash I have already posted the version

Comment: @codegasmer, you posted the version of **java**, not **javac**

Comment: @TagirValeev: if it were the compiler, the error would have come at compile time, not runtime

Comment: @Stultuske, his error did come at compile time.

Comment: my bad, misread it as a result of the java command

Comment: @codegasmer Don't confuse `java` with `javac`, the first is the java virtual machine, the second is the java compiler. `javac` can have a different version from `java`, it all depends on how your environment is set. Please check that `javac -version` is returning the same version as `java -version`.

Comment: @BackSlash and all others thanks for the help means alot

Answer (score 3):

It's the compiler issue. In my environment variable I was pointing towards the old java 7 version. After changing it to 8 the code compiled.

Comment: I suppose you're referring to the JAVA_HOME environment variable